# Varias Url en una clase

Tags: android

Mi app trata de fútbol, con lo cual consta de 30 jornadas, son todas iguales tan solo cambia la URL que es un `Json` cada una, y es donde cojo los datos, osea, hacer como en los `Layouts`, con uno funcionan los 30 `Fragments`.
Lo que quisiera saber es si es posible con un `Fragment`, recorrer estas URL para no tener 30 que es lo que tengo.

Frag_J_01, Frag_J_02 ......... Frag_J_29, Frag_J_30.

```
    public class Frag_J_01 extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    private List<Estadisticas> jornada;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setRetainInstance(true);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);
        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        TextView miTexto = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mi_java);
        miTexto.setText("JORNADA 1");

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        jornada = new ArrayList<>();
        getData();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DecoracionLineaDivisoria(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        if (swipeLayout!=null) {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            swipeLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
            swipeLayout.clearAnimation();
        }
    }

    private void getData(){
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Cargando datos", "Por favor espere...",false,false);

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_JORNADA01,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        parseData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            Estadisticas superHero = new Estadisticas();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                superHero.setFecha(json.getString(Config.TAG_FECHA));
                superHero.setHora(json.getString(Config.TAG_HORA));
                superHero.setEquipo_Local(json.getString(Config.TAG_EQUIPO_LOCAL));
                superHero.setEquipo_Visitante(json.getString(Config.TAG_EQUIPO_VISITANTE));
                superHero.setResultado_Local(json.getString(Config.TAG_RESULTADO_LOCAL));
                superHero.setEstado_Partido(json.getString(Config.TAG_ESTADO));
                superHero.setResultado_Visitante(json.getString(Config.TAG_RESULTADO_VISITANTE));
                superHero.setEscudo_Local("http://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/" + (json.getString(Config.TAG_ESCUDO_LOCAL)));
                superHero.setEscudo_Visitante("http://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/" + (json.getString(Config.TAG_ESCUDO_VISITANTE)));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jornada.add(superHero);
        }
        adapter = new Jornadas_Adapter(jornada, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

¿Seria posible?

Comment: No se si entendi bien, pero por que creas 30 fragments? No seria lo más logico desde la activity ir a la URL, obtener los datos y setearlos a 1 solo fragment?

Comment: Claro es lo que quiero, me puedes orientar,estoy verde aun en esto. Gracias

Comment: Porque son 30 Json y cada un está en una url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible!. Dentro de tu fragmento agrega un método estatico el cual servira para instanciar tu Fragment, realizar esto es una buena practica al instanciar Fragmentos con argumentos:

```
        public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

            private String urlJson;

            public static MyFragment newInstance(String urlJson) {
                MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("urljson", urlJson );
                f.setArguments(args);
                return f;
            }


    private void leeBundle(Bundle bundle) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                urlJson = bundle.getString("urljson");

            }
        }


  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        leeBundle(getArguments());
        }
}
```

Al agregar este método a tu Fragment ahora al instanciar el Fragment, agregarías la url del archivo .json:

```
Fragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance( archivoJson);
```

Con esto solo necesitas un Fragment el cual podrar usar diferentes url. Al utilizar Volley puedes usar esa url para obtener los datos dentro del fragmento:

```
JsonArrayRequest(java.lang.String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

---

Incluso puedes únicamente obtener valores pero no guardarlos en un Bundle:

```
        public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

            private String urlJson;

            public static MyFragment newInstance(String urlJson) {
                this.urlJson = urJson;
                return new MyFragment();
            }               

        }
```